# sql divide column by column max

Tags: sql

I have a column of count and want to divide the column by max of this column to get the rate. 
I tried

```
select t.count/max(t.count)
from table t
group by t.count
```

but failed.
I also tried the one without GROUP BY, still failed.

Order the count desc and pick the first one as dividend didn't work in my case. Consider I have different counts for product subcategory. For each product category, I want to divide the count of subcategory by the max of count in that category. I can't think of a way avoiding aggregate func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the MAX() per category you need a correlated subquery:

```
select t.count*1.0/(SELECT max(t.count) 
                    FROM table a
                    WHERE t.category = a.category)
from table t
```

Or you need to `PARTITION BY` your `MAX()`

```
select t.count/(max(t.count) over (PARTITION BY category))
from table t
group by t.count
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works in all dialects of SQL:

```
select t.count/(select max(t.count) from t)
from table t
group by t.count;
```

Note that some versions of SQL do integer division, so the result will be either 0 or 1.  You can fix this by multiplying by 1.0 or casting to a float.

Most versions of SQL also support:

```
select t.count/(max(t.count) over ())
from table t
group by t.count;
```

The same caveat applies about integer division.

Comment: +1 Although I still think the numerator and denominator should be swapped.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using a subquery to derive the `max` value (including both in the same query might not work the way that you are expecting, since you are grouping on the same column that you are aggregating)

```
Select t.count / (select max(sub.count) from table sub)
from table t
group by t.count
```